# How to display flash message in html for nodejs?

Tags: html, pug

```
#message
 if message
    h1.text-center.error-message #{message}
```

In `Jade` we use the above to display a conditional `error` message
How do we do this in `html` ?

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of context. Where is the error message coming from? Is it coming from an AJAX call? What do you mean HTML? Jade is a template engine for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little vague, but I'll give it a shot:

HTML

```
<div class="alert-container">
     <center>Alert!</center><br /><hr /><br />
     <div class="error">

     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div .alert-container {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     color: #040404;
     font-family: Verdana;
     font-size: 2em;
     border-color: #000000;
     border-radius: 25px;
     text-align: center;
}
div .alert-container .hr {
     color: #040404;
}
div .alert-container center {
     font-size: 3.5em;
}
```

JavaScript (w/ jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('.alert-container').css({visibility: hidden})});
// called on error
function error(text, set){
     if (set){
          $('.error').html(text + '<br /><button onclick="set(\'\', false);">OK</button>');
          $('body').animate({opacity: '25%'}, 'fast');
          $('.alert-container').css({visibility: visible});
     } else {
          $('body').animate({opacity: '100%'}, 'fast');
          $('.alert-container').css({visibility: hidden});
     }
}
```

Disclaimer: I am *definitely* not the best programmer out there, and I certainly have some bad code somewhere. I hope this works for you!

Also, to implement jQuery, add this into your `head` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js" />
```